# Creating Dynamic Custom Validator in Laravel

Tags: laravel, validation, laravel-5.5

Before you read the title and vote as duplicate, hear me out. I haven't been able to find another example of what I am after.

I have a Laravel 5.5 application that uses the built in Laravel Auth class for user management.

If a user tries to perform an action I want to stop/allow the action based on the user's `level`.

I have gone through the docs and found that I can write my own custom validation rules by implementing the `\Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Rule` interface and call it in the controller but I want to, basically, pass the validator the user level and the level required and validate from that.

Can someone please point me in the right direction to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont think the form validation is the best way to make what you want. If you want to restrict actions depending on user permission (here level), you have to create the levels and then check for it before try to validate the form.

I recommend you tu use the Authorization part of Laravel which is well explained in [the doc](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/authorization)